# POST data to Python CGI script via jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cgi

I'm trying to setup a simple script where some data is sent using the jQuery .ajax function to a Python CGI script. The Python script would just make the data posted to it uppercase, and then return that data to the HTML file, where a div would be updated with the content.

I have the code shown below. When I run it, the AJAX call executes, but <strike>the div is not updated with the content.</strike> the div is not updated with the data being sent.

How would I modify this code so that it updates with the data being sent?

I appreciate any help at all.

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Python-jQuery Example</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/post.py",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "html",
                data: "here is data",
                success: function(response){
                        $("#div").html(response);
                        console.log("There is a response"); 
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">Default Stuff</div>
</body>
```

My Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable() 

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print data
```

**EDIT: I have updated my code to what is currently shown, and now the document updates with this string:**

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

**How would I modify my code so that the div updates with the data being sent?**

Comment: Do you see "There is a response" in the console? If so, you should also log response.data, to see what you are getting back from the python script.

Comment: Also, 'success' appears to be deprecated since jQuery 1.5. See the examples for using `.done()` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes, I see "There is a response" in the console.

Comment: I have changed some things in my code, and now this string replaces the contents of my div: "FieldStorage(None, None, []) ". The code in my original post is updated to reflect those changes.

Comment: For one thing, `type: "post"` should be `type: "POST"`.

Comment: I changed that, but I'm still getting that same content in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the "data" inside the $.ajax should be like a hash of a key-value pairs.
try:

```
$.ajax(
....
  data: {
    a: "aa",
    b: "bb"
  }
...
```

If you see in the div something like:

```
MiniFieldStorage('a', 'aa')
```

Then you should access it via:

```
my_param = cgi.getfirst('a')

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print my_param
```

If it's still not working, can you test it via GET instead of POST ?
In addition, what's the structure of the AJAX file(s) that you're accessing ? ( is the file inside a sub-directory ? etc... )

Answer (score 8):

I figured out that the data needs to be formatted as key-value pairs, like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/variousTests/post.py",
            type: "POST",
            data: {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},
            success: function(response){
                    $("#div").html(response);
                }
       });
```

In the Python script, I used this code to get the data from the POST request (it works the exact same way if a GET request is used):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

#the cgi library gets vars from html
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
#this is the actual output
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "The foo data is: " + data["foo"].value
print "<br />"
print "The bar data is: " + data["bar"].value
print "<br />"
print data
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you need to use a newline with the content type printing.

   print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
2. Also, you need to provide the parameter name with your variable **data**. Assuming you are posting the value "xyz" with the parameter "param". So it should  be: **data["param"]** at where the xyz resides.

   print data["xyz"]
3. If the error still persist, then browse the url localhost/cgi-bin/post.py from the browser and check what does it return(with a GET parameter for testing of course).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with your #2? What exactly should I change/add?

Comment: I have updated the #2. I do not know AJAX, so not sure what are you posting from there. Assuming its "param"