# Why is my ajax call not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have an html page that works like a control module and on there is a button that when clicked runs a python script that triggers an alarm. When I click it, it does nothing. Yet I'm not getting any errors in developer tool. The python code works so the script isn't the problem but my ajax request.

Here is the code:

```
<input type='button' class="btn btn-default" value='Alarm ON' id = 'alarm'>

<script>
        $("#alarm").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "lib/scripts/AlarmON.py",
            success: function(response){}
            });
        })
</script>
```

I know if the call would work because an alarm in my room would go off.

EDIT:
For those interested, this is my script:

```
import suds
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
from suds.sax.text import Raw

def main():
    #Sends a network message to device to trigger an alarm
    url = "http://foobar/WSDL/v4.0/iLON100.WSDL"
    client = Client(url, username='ilon', password='ilon', location = 'http://foobar/WSDL/iLON100.WSDL')
    xml = Raw('<Item><UCPTname>Net/MB485/PLC/Virtual Fb/y2</UCPTname><UCPTvalue>TRUE</UCPTvalue></Item>')
    client.service.Write(xml)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

UPDATE I put document.write("hi) inside the success() and it writes hi to the page if the call works, so I'm not sure what is going on..

Comment: How does the python script trigger an alarm?  Generally, I think you'll look at what the script returned in the `success` function handler and then do actions based on that...

Comment: now I'm getting unexpected end token; and removing ; gives me uncaught syntaxerror Unexpected end of input

Comment: ...you're not asking it to do anything in the success callback.

Comment: I just want to run the script the success callback can be empty right? You see I know when the script runs because an alarm in a machine my room goes off.

Comment: You should have an error callback and log the error in the console to know if there's some error!

Comment: See what you're getting in the network tab of the console. 4xx? 2xx? Response?

Comment: I think you are somewhat confused, or maybe I am, I don't think you can run the script on the server through a url request like that?  I think what you really need is to show us the part of your server that should be catching the ajax request.

Comment: I'm not using anything fancy like apache or nginx just using python bottle to host it on local. @Samsquanch I'm getting a 200 response so it knows the script is there..

Comment: Make your script print something out, that should show up in the response tab in the console. If it doesn't, your script isn't running. The 200 response just indicates that it did find the script, but not necessarily that it ran it.

Comment: @user3334690, you can run a python script like this, but I think it needs to be in the cgi-bin. Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723952/post-data-to-python-cgi-script-via-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Samsquanch learn something new everyday,  I'm gonna have to remember that... it doesn't look like the asker's script is in the cgi-bin, so could that be his problem?

Comment: @Samsquanch The script does indeed work, I can execute it from shell.

Comment: You need to see if it's executing by calling it from the browser, which the printing of text will do. You can check the response tab in the console to see if it is or isn't printing that out. If it's not, the script isn't executing.

Comment: Using luke's advice I just decided to route the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute a python script directly like that.  Have a look here:
http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Comment: This is it. Since you are using Bottle, you need to set a route to your AJAX code and send your request there... there is an example here: https://gist.github.com/Arthraim/994641 check line 30

Answer (score 0):

Include also the function error to see what happens:

```
<script>
    $("#alarm").click(function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "lib/scripts/AlarmON.py",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            var status = xhr.status;
            var text = xhr.statusText;
            console.log( status + ': ' + text);
        }
      });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Its pointless in adding the error, cause the success always works when I click the button.